# tidyr: wide to long of column names

Tags: r, tidyr

Say I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(Day=c(1,2,3), Asia.Temp=c(30,20,10), Asia.Humidity=c(0.5,0.2,0.1), Europe.Temp=c(50,10,20), Europe.Humidity=c(0.2,0.2,0.7), Africa.Temp=c(70,60,80), Africa.Humidity=c(0.5,0.2,0.7))
```

i.e.

```
  Day Asia.Temp Asia.Humidity Europe.Temp Europe.Humidity Africa.Temp
1   1        30           0.5          50             0.2          70
2   2        20           0.2          10             0.2          60
3   3        10           0.1          20             0.7          80
  Africa.Humidity
1             0.5
2             0.2
3             0.7
```

I would like to `gather` regions into a single column, and let Temp and Humidity vary.

Currently, I am doing this using the base function `reshape`.

```
reshape(df, timevar="Region", times=c("Asia", "Europe", "Africa"), v.names=c("Temp", "Humidity"), varying=names(df)[2:ncol(df)], direction="long")
```

I will get what I want:

```
         Day Region Temp Humidity id
1.Asia     1   Asia  0.5       30  1
2.Asia     2   Asia  0.2       20  2
3.Asia     3   Asia  0.1       10  3
1.Europe   1 Europe  0.2       50  1
2.Europe   2 Europe  0.2       10  2
3.Europe   3 Europe  0.7       20  3
1.Africa   1 Africa  0.5       70  1
2.Africa   2 Africa  0.2       60  2
3.Africa   3 Africa  0.7       80  3
```

(The *id* column is unnecessary.)

I am being unsuccessful reproducing this with `tidyr`. I am trying to learn tidyverse, to make my code clearer. I am able to reshape a given column, but not to do something like...

Is this possible with `tidyr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure is possible using `tidyr`. For a "genuinely long and tidy" result, I would omit the final `%>% spread(Measurement, value)`; try that and see how it looks.

[Here's a useful guide](http://www.milanor.net/blog/reshape-data-r-tidyr-vs-reshape2/) to `tidyr` versus `reshape`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr) 
# or just use library(tidyverse)
# also df is not a great variable name :)

df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Day) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("Region", "Measurement"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  spread(Measurement, value)

  Day Region Humidity Temp
1   1 Africa      0.5   70
2   1   Asia      0.5   30
3   1 Europe      0.2   50
4   2 Africa      0.2   60
5   2   Asia      0.2   20
6   2 Europe      0.2   10
7   3 Africa      0.7   80
8   3   Asia      0.1   10
9   3 Europe      0.7   20
```

Comment: Could you just please add a small comment about what the `separate`/`spread` combo is doing?

Comment: Please read the linked guide. `separate` splits values in column `key` into two columns, `Region` and `Measurement`. So `Africa.Temp` becomes `Region = Africa`, `Measurement = Temp`. `spread` then creates columns from the values in `Measurement`, _i.e._ `Temp` and `Humidity`. Play around by successively omitting lines starting from the last to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with the `pivot_longer` (from the new version of `tidyr_1.0.0`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  rename_at(-1, ~str_replace(., "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)", "\\2_\\1")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Day, values_to = c("Temp", "Humidity"), 
      names_to = c(".value", "Region"), names_pattern = '([^_]+)_([^_]+)')
# A tibble: 9 x 4
#    Day Region  Temp Humidity
#  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1 Asia      30      0.5
#2     1 Europe    50      0.2
#3     1 Africa    70      0.5
#4     2 Asia      20      0.2
#5     2 Europe    10      0.2
#6     2 Africa    60      0.2
#7     3 Asia      10      0.1
#8     3 Europe    20      0.7
#9     3 Africa    80      0.7
```